# How to split a string in a list into multiple string based on whitespaces in python?

Tags: python, regex, list, split, list-comprehension

Here, 'list' is my list of strings, i want to split 'a b' into 'a','b' and merge it back into the list with other strings

```
list = ['abc','a b', 'a b c','1234']

Expected Output after splitting = ['abc','a','b','a','b','c','1234']
```

Comment: Loop over the list and split based on space character. what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
lis = ['abc', 'a b', 'a b c', '1234']
lis1 = []
for i in lis:
    b = i.split()
    lis1.extend(b)
print lis1
```

Output:-

```
['abc', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', '1234']
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

`' '.join(list).split(' ')`

output

`['abc', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', '1234']`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using :

```
[y for x in list for y in x.split(' ')]
```